# make use of inbuilt google maps services in our custom application android

Tags: android, google-maps, service, built-in

However every android smartphone has inbuilt google map service named        `com.google.android.apps.maps`.

Now if i am developing location based application then can i make use of this service to get latitude and longitude value of the user.

Because besides writing another service to achieve same functionality it will be good idea to use the inbuilt service that will reduce systems overload.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a inbuilt location service that you can register with to receive updates, but the way you should be getting location is using Google Play Services, which has an updated location provider service, that is more accurate, and more efficient.

Check it out [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html)